# what is the difference between "command && command" and "command ; command"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash, shell

I see these two usage on Ubuntu "command && command" and "command ; command",
 e.g. `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`

What would differ if I use `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade`?
 I am not asking for this specific usage but in general what is the difference between these two usage?

Comment: Win command-line and batch have the same feature: `& (simple sequencing), && (conditional AND) and || (conditional OR)`.

Comment: See also: [Bash Reference Manual – List of commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists). In general, there's nothing you can't find in the documentation; it's really worth looking at if you have a question about specific syntax elements.

Comment: @Karan And for completeness, bash (linux/Ubuntu) has `||` as well.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

`&&` is a logical operator. `;` is simple sequencing.

In `cmd1 && cmd2`, cmd2 will only be run if cmd1 exits with a successful return code.

Whereas in `cmd1; cmd2`, cmd2 will run regardless of the exit status of cmd1 (assuming you haven't set your shell to exit on all failure in your script or something).

On a related note, with `cmd1 || cmd2`, using the `||` 'OR' logical operator, cmd2 will only be run if cmd1 fails (returns a non-zero exit code).

These logical operators are sometimes used in scripts in place of a basic if statement. For example,

```
if [[ -f "$foo" ]]; then mv "$foo" "${foo%.txt}.mkd"; fi
```

...can be more concisely achieved with:

```
[[ -f "$foo" ]] && mv "$foo" "${foo%.txt}.mkd"
```

Comment: I find it a little bit fallacious because from my understanding, successful return code means 0, which, when cast into bool, gives a logical false. So going by the philosophy of Mccarthy evaluation used in most languages, it should immediately return false rather than evaluating (running) the next statement.

Comment: @Della 0 corresponding to false and non-0 to true is just a convention; for command exit statuses, it makes more sense to use the opposite convention, so that's what the shell does.

Answer (score 36):

### Syntax

```
command1 && command2
```

***command2*** is executed if, and only if, `command1` returns an exit status of zero (***true***). In other words, run `command1` and if it is successfull, then run `command2`.

```
command1 ; command2
```

Both ***command1*** and ***command2*** will be executed regardless. The semicolon allows you to type many commands on one line.

***Related***:

```
command1 || command2
```

***command2*** is executed if, and only if, ***command1*** returns a non-zero exit status. In other words, run `command1` successfully or run `command2`.

---

### Example

**`&&`** operator:

```
$ rm /tmp/filename && echo "File deleted"
```

**`;`** operator:

```
$ echo "foo" ; echo "bar"
```

***`||`*** operator:

```
$ cat /tmp/filename 2>/dev/null || echo "Failed to open file"
```

---

### External Links

1. [Linuxtopia.org](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/ops.html)
2. [Tldp.org](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html)